# Does Kafka support creating projections from multiple category streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, alpakka, akka.net-streams

We are using EventStore for our event sourced solution. We would like to export events into Kafka and do stream processing using Kafka. In EventStore each type of stream belongs to a category, for example Order, Customer, Payment etc.  Under each category you have individual streams, for example Order-123, Order-124 etc.
Now these events maintain global order across all streams, and one can consume that in that order.
My question is, is it possible to take these streams and create a new projected stream in Kafka while maintaining the order of events. For example, take these 3 category streams, and create a new one for example CustomerActivity.  Given that Order and Payment have CustomerId, that would serve as partition key for new streams in CustomerAcivity partition.

Same Q, for Akka.Net streams.